# What would happen if a slab of stone materialized in a spot where a PC is?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew

My next adventure involves a trapdoor slab of stone (well, marble) dematerializing, and materializing back in place after 2 rounds.
I haven't decided yet what will happen if a PC is holding on to the edge, for instance.
I guess the closest to a RAW precedent is Etherealness, which says to expel to the nearest free space, but that seems a little less intuitive when it's not the PC but the solid matter that is 'respawning'. Also, if it's a limb sticking *through* the place where it's respawning, I'm not sure that makes the most sense.
I'm debating whether I should just encase their limb in the stone and let them find a way to chisel it out or something.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Agreed with other voters that this is too opinion based. We can answer "Is there precedent for this" or "Do the rules say anything on this topic", but "What would you do?" is not on topic here. Feel free to edit your question to someone we can help with. if you're interested. And welcome to the site :)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this. We can also provide subjective expertise guidance on how to handle a difficult issue that the rules do not answer. Perhaps ironically, WakiNadiVellir's comments havwe more or less provided exactly the kind of guidance that would make for a great answer—in other words I believe this is fully answerable with expert guidance about how the querent can work out how they want it to work themselves. We should not give mere opinions as our answers, but the question as asked is not solely answerable by only opinions.

Comment: @doppelgreener I think you're right, but I think it needs more details in the question before we can do a good job of answering

Comment: Alright. It seems I should've done some more research into the website etiquette before posting, but I feel a bit weird editing now that I've gotten such a great answer already. If I understand correctly I should've made it more explicit that I was looking for more rules sources, or 'subjective expertise guidance' as doppelgreener aptly put it?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, this is a very subjective situation and ultimately it depends on your goal with the trap as a DM.

With that in mind, I'll start with a few suggestions that I came up with starting from your chosen RAW precedent, and then I’ll discuss trap design in general – this may help you decide what you want the reappearing stone (and the rest of the trap!) to do.

## Disappearing Stone interaction

### Option 1: RAW (Etherealness)

As you pointed out, this is the simplest case - the PC is shoved out of the way of the rematerializing stone. If they’re most of the way up, they get shoved to freedom. If they are mostly hanging below, they are pushed down into the pit! If they’re somehow exactly halfway, well, that’s what a d2 is for.

I don’t have a ready example of where I have used this in a trap scenario, but this would be my approach to your RAW interpretation.

### Option 2: Bludgeoning Damage

This option follows from the first option, but in addition to being shoved, the suddenly rematerialized stone causes bludgeoning damage. I think of this as the “coughed up” option, as the rematerializing marble peristaltically shoves the PC out of the way.

This is an option I favour in many situations, not just in traps; it is a quick solution that offers an immediate, generally minor, setback and provides the energy and emotional hit of a close call. Examples I have employed (not all traps) include:

- PC almost crushed under a portcullis
- A Gnome PC attempts to 'dodge' the Indiana Jones boulder trap by
  squeezing down at the foot of the wall
- PC falls partway out of a car and is scraped by the road before
  recovering

### Option 3: Stuck

This is your “PC’s arm gets caught” option. They are now trapped in stone and must be freed by creative player action. Perhaps it is as simple as re-triggering the trap and pulling their friend free as the stone dematerializes again (and before they fall the rest of the way though), or maybe they need to cut them out. Expect your players to get very outside the box with this one!

You could increase the difficulty by combining this with bludgeoning damage as per option 2 - the stone is crushing until they are freed.

I have also enjoyed many a trap like this. In fact, a trap whose entire purpose revolves around restraining a PC can often be used to great effect. I’ve snapped bear traps on PCs in a flooding hallway, and in one RIFTS session largely inspired by the DNA collection machine from the Judge Dredd movie, I had a PC get their hand stuck in a blood sucking machine while various monsters poured into the room.

Other classic traps in this genre would include nets or the tripwire snare that pulls you feet first into the air.

### Option 4: Petrification

A more extreme version of option three, if desired – the PC is not only trapped, but now made of marble, as per *Petrification*. This is an incredibly powerful, dangerous trap for low-level parties, and more of a mild annoyance for any parties with mid-to-high level divine casters and access to *Greater Restoration*.

Not quite the same, but one such example would be the *Imprisonment* (Minimus Containment) trap on a door in

> Out of the Abyss

which magically transports the victim from outside the locked door to inside a gem hidden within the room. The party can find and recover the gem, and a 9th level *Dispel Magic* will restore the trapped creature.

This could be a PC-ending event or one requiring serious questing to resolve for a low-to-mid level party, but once you have a level 17+ spellcaster it is more of an irritation - assuming you can recover the gem!

### Option 5: Pancake

This is the most extreme option of all - the PC is crushed and killed by the rematerializing stone. I would definitely give them a save of some sort to get free first, and even then I would be careful; not many players appreciate being put in an out of the blue 'save or die' situation.

I added this option for completeness’ sake (I view these five options as a gradient of severity), but as [@NautArch](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/23024/nautarch) mentions in the comments below, this sort of “Rocks Fall, You Die” approach makes for a poor play experience. No matter the odds, a straight percent chance to lose your character is an unsatisfying experience. I can only think of one occasion where I did this, and that was at the tail end of a string of hard checks and failures across an entire session, on a quest the PCs knew would be beyond challenging.

## Trap Design Concepts

Note: I will be exclusively using rules from the trap design section in the DMG, starting on page 120.

Traps are divided into three general categories:

- Setbacks (minimal HP loss or use of party resources)
- Dangerous (moderate HP loss or use of party resources)
- Deadly (serious HP loss and possible character death, significant use
  of party resources)

These categories are described in terms of a trap’s DC to save against or its attack bonus (traps will require one or both of these), and the suggested damage ranges by severity according to character level – 4d10 is a terrifying number for a party of 3rd characters, but by 7th it is merely concerning.

Further, traps can be considered a separate encounter – they can require similar effort and resource use to a fight or puzzle and can often leave the party wanting to use a short rest if the trap encounter goes poorly!

So, when designing a trap it is good to consider its position in the adventuring day. Will there be a lot of fighting? Will this trap force them to use resources and make compromises that make that fight more challenging and exciting, or will it deplete them so badly your party of 10th level adventurers get rolled by kobolds?

Without knowing how difficult you want this trap to be, I will stick to general discussion about how you might design it and give a range of options. I will also use the same save DC ranges the section provides for spot checks, for consistency.

## Trap Outline: Dematerializing Stone Pit

First, a quick analysis of the trap parts. Based on your description, this is a relatively simple two-part trap: a pit trap featuring a well-disguised trap door – a section of stone that looks highly similar (or identical) to the stone around it. With that in mind, we now have to figure out how to spot the trap, how it might be disabled by the party, and what happens if it is triggered.

### Spotting the Trap

The dematerializing feature suggests a higher DC to spot it, as you specified our trapdoor is composed of the same stone as the surrounding space. Thankfully, we still have a good example to lean on in the DMG:

**Hidden Pit (p.122):** “A successful DC 15 Wisdom (Perception) check discerns the absence of foot traffic over the section of floor that forms the pit’s cover”.

This would make sense for a difficult but not impossible trap to spot. We could rationalize this as the lack of dust or debris, since presumably it falls into the pit when the stone dematerializes. A DC of 15 is the upper end of the “Dangerous” trap category, so this would be appropriate if you plan on a serious inconvenience for your party.

If you have more of a challenge in mind, we could say that all of the dust, debris, and other material on top of the stone dematerializes and rematerializes too and raise the DC into the Deadly category of 16+.

Conversely, if DC 15 is too high for your party, you could add that in addition to the lack of anything on this suspiciously clean stone, it is also one perfect carved tile. This one stone is set off from the others by a thin seam, the boundary for whatever magical effect causes the block to dematerialize. Described in this way, we could bring the DC to spot it down into the “Setback” range of 10-11.

### Disabling the Trap

As this is a magical trap, the simplest approach would be the *Dispel Magic* spell, which could temporarily or permanently disable the trap (p. 121).

As an aside, this is a real stone that dematerializes. That suggests that *Dispel Magic* would render the stone inert and able to be walked across. In contrast, if it was illusory stone, the pit would be revealed and crossing it would still be a challenge. Not presenting this to suggest it is a better or worse design, just a contrasting option for your trapdoor!

As this is a magical trap, it may not be possible to disarm it by mundane means. I have seen some DMs allow an Arcana or Thieve’s Tools check to modify or add runes to a trap’s hidden enchantment, but you are not required to allow these – you are the DM, after all. Depending on the width of the trap, a mundane solution could be as simple as a good jump.

### Triggering the Trap

We have already discussed the dematerializing stone portion, so the pit itself is likely much simpler; in the simplest case, the PCs miss any stone-rematerializing issues and simply fall into the pit.

For this, make the pit as deep (+1d6 damage per 10 feet they fall), and as spiked or acid-filled as you feel necessary to cause your desired amount of harm, and call it a day.

Do note that the same DC ranges as above could (and generally, should!) apply to any saves to reduce damage when falling in – Setbacks are easy to avoid (DC 10-11, perhaps to avoid twisting your ankle on the landing), Dangerous traps more difficult (DC 12-15, avoid the worst of the spikes), and Deadly traps highly unlikely to avoid at all (DC 16+, somehow avoid getting coated in the waist-deep acid).

## *Fin*

It's an interesting trap concept, and I hope this information helps you put together a trap you want and that your party will always remember, when the coming rain makes their knee twinge.

Comment: Have you designed or seen in use the traps and recommendations you've got above? We differ from other sites in that we expect our answers to have a solid [citations and support](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8696) and that is currently missing in your answer. Adding that in turns this into what appears to be a bit more on the idea generation end of things and be more about an expert showing their expertise as guidance.

Comment: I'd also be very wary to make a save against Rocks Fall, You Die.

Comment: @NautArch Good feedback, appreciate it. Added in references to places I have used or seen similar traps.

Comment: Amazing feedback! The players ended up letting themselves drop straight through for fear of getting seperated, so in the end it didn't come up, but it's sure to give my thoughts some guidance if ever it comes up again. Thanks for the extensive effort!